# How Does Netplwiz Get a UserName?

Tags: windows-identity

If a Windows username is created in a `xxx@domain.com` email syntax, the `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` value returned is in the `DOMAIN\UserName` syntax.

How does `Netplwiz` retrieve and display usernames properly in their email syntax? Can that be done for the currently logged in user?

What classes/methods/fields are available for retrieval?

Comment: FWIW, `netplwiz` never shows my domain login details in UPN format. How'd you get it to do that?

Comment: I can find out _exactly_ how `netplwiz` works after spending a bit of time in _Ghidra_... but a quicker solution would be to speculate that in an AD domain environment it probably uses ADSI to get the latest up-to-date info from LDAP, while everything else probably goes through [`NetQueryDisplayInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netquerydisplayinformation)

Answer (score 0):

> If a Windows username is created in a xxx@domain.com email syntax...

They're more formally referred to as *User Principal Name*, or UPN for short precisely to avoid confusion with identically-formatted SMTP e-mail addresses.

<sub>**Nostalgia time!**: Back in the days of Windows 2000 I remember the mood and expectation was that UPNs would *eventually* be mapped to a valid e-mail address *and* they'd replace NT's `DOMAIN\USERNAME`-style logins long before Windows Server 2003 came out - well, that never happened, and despite Microsoft *really* pushing people to use UPNs in the early 2000s I think they realised it wasn't going to go anywhere by the time Windows 7 came out.</sub>

> How does `Netplwiz` retrieve and display usernames properly in their email syntax?

(*Ghidra speedrun time...*)

I noticed that `netplwiz` uses COM to access and call-out into services that would be resolved at runtime and so *it's possible* that `netplwiz` may be using some hither-unknown COM interface/service to perform some aspects of name translation, so the function list here is not exhaustive.

But moving on to what a straightforward static-analysis can tell us:

- Looking at the Imports table, ``netplwiz.dll` directly references dozens of Win32 libraries, and from those I saw these imported funcs that can perform name translation (either searching by UPN or login-name and resolving it to a SID, or vice-versa; or translating between them).

  - [`API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL::DsCrackNamesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdsapi/nf-ntdsapi-dscracknamesw)
  - [`API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-0.DLL::LookupAccountNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountnamew)
  - `API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-0.DLL::LookupAccountSidW`
  - `API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDL-L1-1-0.DLL::ConvertSidToStringSidW`
  - `DSROLE.DLL::DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation`
  - `SAMCLI.DLL::NetLocalGroupEnum`
  - `SAMCLI.DLL::NetLocalGroupGetMembers`
  - `SAMCLI.DLL::NetUserGetInfo`
  - [`SECUR32.DLL::TranslateNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-translatenamew)

---

There are other parts of Win32 that can do this too, which `netplziwz` doesn't use, like:

- [`NetQueryDisplayInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netquerydisplayinformation).
- [`NetUserEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum)
- [`GetUserNameExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexw)

---

> Can that be done for the currently logged in user?

Yes.

From the command-line, just run `whoami /upn`

I poked around in `whoami.exe` *just to be sure* and it looks like it gets your username in [UPN format using `GetUserNameExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexw) [by passing `NameUserPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/ne-secext-extended_name_format) (i.e. the integer value `8`) as the first argument:

[image]

Comment: I didn't mention that I was attempting to build a .NET MAUI based controller which limits my ability to use direct Windows libraries. I looked at the numerous pointers provided and didn't see how they might be applied given that limitation. I am trying to immediately capture the actual userid entered during login.

Comment: @MarcGeorge Why are you using MAUI if your program is only going to run on Windows?

Comment: In the end, I want to have the app available across the other OS's. At the moment I am only developing and building the prototype on Windows.

Comment: Then put the call to `GetUserNameW` in an `#if` block or with a runtime platform check.